# Jqplot line chart multiple series

Tags: jqplot

```
[[["09251A0428",90],["10251A0547",37]],[["09251A0428",4],["10251A0547",54]]]
```

Above data contains two series. x values of each series are same. if the x values are numeric the jqplot displays line chart with two series as normal. but we need to display strings on x axis and for each string corresponding series values.

How to set strings on xaxis for multiple series line chart of jqplot?

Answer (score 1):

I have preapared an example for you based on the data you gave:
[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dH7Hm/2/)

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var chartData = [[["09251A0428",90],["10251A0547",37]],[["09251A0428",4],["10251A0547",54]]];


function PlotChart(chartData) {

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', chartData, {
        title: 'Mouse Cursor Tracking',
        seriesDefaults: {

            pointLabels: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                pad: 1,
                // a factor multiplied by the data range on the axis to give the            
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                // renderer to use to draw the axis,     
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%b %#d'
                }
            },
            yaxis: {

            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true
        }
    });
}

PlotChart(chartData);
```

Comment: thanks,  it is possible with `renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer`